# Can't import netstandard1.6 project into netcore1.0 app

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've created a fresh Asp.Net Core WebApi application and a .NET Core library that I intend to reference in that appliation.

- The application is a netcoreapp1.0
- The library is netstandard1.6
- dotnet --version is 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177

I've referenced the library in the app, however it seems that the application is unable to resolve anything within that library.

- Can anyone explain to me what is wrong with this? I assumed it should work out of the box?
- Can anyone explain what would I need to do in order to have this run cross-platform? ex win10 and ubuntu ?

**web api app**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
    },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50"
        //"dotnet5.6",
        //"portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "PoC.ServiceDiscovery": {
          "version": "1.0.0-*",
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64" :  {} ,
    "ubuntu.16.04-x64":  {} 
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

**library**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {},
    "ubuntu.16.04-x64": {}
  }
}
```

Regards

Comment: I think this should be another question: **Can anyone explain what would I need to do in order to have this run cross-platform? ex win10 and ubuntu ?**

Comment: Please paste the `project.json` of both projects.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that, despite the styling from StackOverflow, `//`-based comments are not valid JSON. I'm surprised what you have works in that context.

Comment: Can you post this to github?

Comment: sure, gimme a few minutes

Comment: https://github.com/mmisztal1980/PoC.Api.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Remove the `runtimes` from the library's project.json. Your library is defining a set of APIs that it utilizes (the .NET Standard 1.6 APIs). The implementations of those APIs which are utilized is chosen by the runtime that depends on your library. It might work with them listed, but it doesn't make any sense for a .NET Standard library.

(2) Your library lacks a name. Give it a name so you can reference it in your WebAPI `project.json`. I'm going to assume it will be called `PoC.ServiceDiscovery` for the sake of clarity.

(3) Put `PoC.ServiceDiscovery`, assuming that is your library's name, into the normal list of `dependencies` in the WebAPI's `project.json` file, right next to the `Microsoft.*` libraries.

(4) You need to give your WebAPI project knowledge of where to look for this library. There are two main ways of doing this. One way is to share the library using a package manager like NuGet or MyGet (which requires updates to a `NuGet.config` file) or, what I think you want to do in your scenario, a local project reference. In that case, add a `global.json` file in your root directory with an array of relative paths that contain your library and WebAPI projects, and make the dependency in the WebAPI project a project reference. That would mean it would look like this: `"PoC.ServiceDiscovery": { "target": "project" }`

If you would like to see an example, [here is a very simple library](https://github.com/invio/Invio.Hashing) I've written that [uses .NET Standard for the library](https://github.com/invio/Invio.Hashing/blob/master/src/Invio.Hashing/project.json), a [project reference](https://github.com/invio/Invio.Hashing/blob/master/test/Invio.Hashing.Tests/project.json) for the library's test project, and a [global.json file](https://github.com/invio/Invio.Hashing/blob/master/global.json) that allows the `dotnet` command line tool to know where to look for the library when running the tests.

Comment: If you really want to get your hands dirty, clone the repository, run `dotnet restore`, then `dotnet test -f netcoreapp1.0 ./test/Invio.Hashing.Tests`.

Comment: I'm getting a "the given key was not present in the dictionary" error while adding the project reference

Comment: Doing what? For general debugging guidance, add the `dotnet --version` info to your question (while making sure you have the most up-to-date version), and run `dotnet restore` anytime you update your `project.json` file.

Comment: Adding ```"PoC.ServiceDiscovery": { "target": "project" },``` to the dependencies, makes the package restore fail with that error

Comment: dotnet --version info added

Comment: I made a little example project for you on github that you can take as a starting point and modify for your purposes. https://github.com/carusology/so-40861127 Run `dotnet restore` at the root, then `dotnet run` from `src/Example.Web`. You'll see the constructor of the library spit out its `Console.WriteLine()`. I notice your `imports` are different on your WebAPI project. Perhaps that's triggering this obscure error?

Comment: amazingly, having copied the project.json(s) from the file made the whole thing work like it's supposed to!

Comment: spoke to soon, the whole thing compiled, but the web project cannot resolve the namespace from the lib project :/

Comment: Copying which `project.json` from what file? I can't follow your comment. I would expect namespaces to fail if you put your `project.json` files into the project I listed, or vice versa, as the namespaces of the example I put together are `Example.*` where yours are `PoC.*`.

Comment: I cloned your repo and checked it out. I think the fundamental problem you were running into was `UseServiceDiscovery()` is your extension method, but you were trying to call `AddServiceDiscovery()` (presumably because that is a similar syntax to `AddMvc()` and it got stuck in your head). After I cleaned up the dependencies on `PoC.ServiceDiscovery`, using the correct name worked fine for me.

Comment: weird, after checking out the code, I'm still getting: CS1061 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'UseServiceDiscovery' and no extension method 'UseServiceDiscovery' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) PoC.Api..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Answer (score 0):

At first there is no longer separated ASP.NET WebApi because its now a part of ASP.NET MVC

But backing to main topic - .NET Standard is only higher level API abstract. Support for .NET Core 1.0 does not mean that run cross plat (because it support also .NET Framework, Universal Windows Platform etc.). So you have 2 ways to do in library:

- Remove netstandard1.6 and replace netcoreapp1.0
- Remove runtimes

For more informationi suggest read https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md

Comment: I thought I needed the runtimes in order to have this run on selected platforms? What should I replace netcoreapp1.0 with?

Comment: @Maciej Targeting runtime is in main project not in library using abstract API .NET Standard

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\YourProjectName\YourProjectName.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

to the targeted .csproj project.